# Inserting custom TIMESTAMP value in the Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to insert custom date time in the oracle database where the `ITEM_TIME_DATE` column has the `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO items 
    (ITEM_AUTHOR_ID, ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, ITEM_TIME_DATE, ITEM_STATUS) 
    VALUES 
    ('0', 'test title', 'test des', TO_TIMESTAMP('12-23-2015 8:00 PM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 0);
```

Though the custom date should convert to a timestamp format, but i am getting this error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

I am using Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 (Windows 10) 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format in the `TO_TIMESTAMP` call doesn't match the data. Use:

```
INSERT INTO items 
  (ITEM_AUTHOR_ID, ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, ITEM_TIME_DATE, ITEM_STATUS) 
VALUES 
  ('0', 'test title', 'test des', TO_TIMESTAMP('12-23-2015 8:00 PM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI AM'), 0);
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `:SS` or add seconds `:00` to your time, and add `AM` to the format.

This works:

```
INSERT INTO items 
    (ITEM_AUTHOR_ID, ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, ITEM_TIME_DATE, ITEM_STATUS) 
    VALUES 
    ('0', 'test title', 'test des', TO_TIMESTAMP('12-23-2015 8:00:00 PM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `HH24:MI:SS` as the date format and so your insert value should be

TO_TIMESTAMP('12-23-2015 8:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')